# Mejor práctica en listas para dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en ASP.NET-MVC 5; donde debo utilizar muchos elementos de tipo `<select>` con una importante variedad de opciones

El caso sería el siguiente

Tengo una clase que esta únicamente avocada a generar las distintas listas de un modelo; por ejemplo

```
public class Listas
{
   public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaEjemplo()
    {
      IList<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>
      {
       new SelectListItem { Text="0,625" , Value = "0,625"},
       new SelectListItem { Text="1" , Value = "1"},
       new SelectListItem { Text="1,25", Value="1,25" }
      };

     return items;
  }
}
```

En mi modelo, lo estoy implementando de la siguiente manera

```
public class ModeloEjemplo
{
   public string ejemplo { get; set; }
   public decimal otroejemplo { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaEjemplo
      {
        get
        {
            return Listas.GetPorcentajePuntos().OrderBy(x => x.Text);
        }
     }
}
```

Y en la vista la implemento como

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.otroejemplo, Model.ListaEjemplo)
```

El asunto es; 
manejarlo de esa manera, ¿es una buena práctica? Es algo sumamente importante para mi poder administrar el tema de performance con las listas, ya que como decía arriba tengo un gran número de desplegables

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Hacer una vista tipada siempre es buena práctica. Saludos